# Is the mean of the left-truncated binomial distribution convex in p?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, convex, truncated-distributions

The expectation of the binomial distribution of successes in $G$ trials, left-truncated at $R$, with success probability $p$, is

$$
E[X|p] = \frac{\sum_{l=R}^Gl\phi(l)}{\sum_{l=R}^G\phi(l)}
$$

where

$$
\phi(l) = \binom{G}{l}p^l(1-p)^{G-l}.
$$

Is this convex in $p$? It looks as if it is.

**Update**

In work so far, I've taken the first derivative as

$$
\frac{d}{dp}E[X|p] = 
\frac{\sum_{l=R}^{G}\sum_{m=l+1}^{G}(l-m)^{2}\phi(l)\phi(m)}{p(1-p)(\sum_{l=R}^G\phi(l))^2}.
$$

This used the fact (I hope!) that

$$
\frac{d}{dp} \phi(l) = \frac{l - Gp}{p(1-p)} \phi(l)
$$

and simplified a double sum $\sum_{l=R}^G \sum_{m=R}^G...$ by merging pairs of terms to produce $\sum_{l=R}^G \sum_{m=l+1}^G...$.

Comment: Start with the definition of a convex function, and then see if this definition applies here. Have you tried this already?

Comment: I have written it out, but proving the relevant inequality looks hard!  $aE[X|p] +(1-a)E[X|q] > E[X|ap+(1-a)q]$... it's not easy to see how this will simplify

Comment: Looking at this numerically, on some examples, I did not encounter counterexamples, but that is no proof  ... didn't find a proof

Comment: Why do you denote this point of truncation by $R$? I would use $L$ for “left”.

Comment: since this function is smooth, a better definition of convexity is having an everywhere positive second derivative.

Comment: Also, could you tell us your motivation for this?

Comment: It's a piece of theory in a model we are building.

Comment: I don't have time at the moment, but your truncated expectation looks like what is called "residual mean life" (apart from a subtraction of R) in survival and reliability}

Answer (score 0):

Since the function of interest is defined over a continuum of real values of $p$ you can check its convexity using standard calculus methods.  Consider a general ratio function:

$$f(p) = \frac{g(p)}{h(p)}.$$

The quotient rules says that:

$$f'(p) = \frac{g'(p) h(p) - g(p) h'(p)}{h(p)^2},$$

and the second-order quotient rules says that:

$$f''(p) = \frac{[g''(p) h(p) - g(p) h''(p)] h(p) - 2 [g'(p) h(p) - g(p) h'(p)] h'(p)}{h(p)^3}.$$

Convexity occurs when, for all $0<p<1$ we have:

$$[g''(p) h(p) - g(p) h''(p)] h(p) > 2 [g'(p) h(p) - g(p) h'(p)] h'(p).$$

Check this condition against the numerator and denominator functions in your example and this will tell you whether your function is convex.

Comment: I agree, but I haven't managed to prove the relevant inequality. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The entire point of the question is that this brute force attack on the problem looks intractable or, at least, very messy.

Comment: @whuber: There is a big difference between intractable and messy.  In any case, if you find an alternative (simpler) means of showing convexity in this case, I'll happily accept that critique.

Comment: @dash2: I'm afraid the only idea I have here is for you to keep practicing your algebra/calculus until you can show one way or the other that the condition holds.  Either you will find a $p$ that falsifies the condition (in which case it is not convex) or you will be able to establish the required inequality.

Comment: @whuber: The answer also simplifies things by removing consideration of the denominator parts of the derivatives, which is already an advance on the material in the question.

Comment: That much is obvious.  The issue here is that brute-force differentiation doesn't appear to get us any closer to a solution unless you can demonstrate the sums simplify or otherwise analyze them.